# What should I do if the etcd installation hangs?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I am trying to install etcd 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

This command `aptitude install etcd` results in a variety of complex messages.

This command `apt-get install etcd` results in this message:

```
E: Package 'etcd' has no installation candidate
```

I downloaded a .tar.gz file for etcd 2.2.  I expanded it to install it from this stand alone package.  I then entered the new directory that was created.  When I run ./etcd I get this message and the installation hangs:

```
2017-03-31 20:39:48.384030 I | raft: raft.node: ce2a822cea30bfca elected leader ce2a822cea30bfca at term 4
2017-03-31 20:39:48.384708 I | etcdserver: published {Name:default ClientURLs:[http://localhost:2379 http://localhost:4001]} to cluster 7e27652122e8b2ae
```

What should I do?

I expected `./etcd` to progress and allow the etcdctl commands to work.  There is no evidence etcd is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs it seems ok. Do you mean after printing the mentioned lines command prompt returns?
Run below command from the same directory and see if you are able to communicate.

```
./etcdctl set mykey "this is awesome" 
./etcdctl get mykey
```

I used below steps for installation and it worked fine for me:

```
curl -L  https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/download/v2.1.0-rc.0/etcd-v2.1.0-rc.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz -o etcd-v2.1.0-rc.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar xzvf etcd-v2.1.0-rc.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
cd etcd-v2.1.0-rc.0-linux-amd64
./etcd
```

Comment: I get "No such file or directory."  etcd has not been installed. How do I install it?  The installation hangs.  Nothing I try ever works.

Comment: Added instruction for installation that I used.